# Flutter app drops java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError (couldn't find “libflutter.so”) Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.12.13+hotfix.9)

Tags: flutter, dart

i see below error on crashlytics firebase a lot on many different devices for me its not reproduced.

flutter team not able to solve this issue 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37566

Flutter (Channel unknown, v1.12.13+hotfix.9):

note: the apk contain the libflutter.so binaries.

Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kw.ltd.twitter_app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kw.ltd.twitter_app-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:984)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1582)
       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.startInitialization(FlutterLoader.java:122)
       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.startInitialization(FlutterLoader.java:93)
       at io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.startInitialization(FlutterMain.java:45)
       at io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication.onCreate(FlutterApplication.java:22)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5405)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, i find the solution!

1.add target-platform=android-arm in gradle.properties

2.edit build.gradle in your root folder

```
rootProject.setProperty('target-platform', 'android-arm')

subprojects {
    project.setProperty('target-platform', 'android-arm')
}
```

Comment: Don't use this! It means that the app on devices other than 'android-arm' will not work ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building with this command:

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64
```

This worked for me!

Comment: yes did not solve the issue, as i said many users complaining about this issue.                               flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64

Comment: I understand... Does Flutter doctor -v say anything about that?

Comment: no everything looks fine, i had 5 app i am getting at least a bug each day about this issue, no fix for now